# How to change "Access Denied" for user 'agenda'@'localhost' (Using Password: YES) on line 9

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
class MySQLDB 
{
    var $connection; //The MySQL database connection
    var $num_active_users; //Number of active users viewing site
    var $num_active_guests; //Number of active guests viewing site
    var $num_members; //Number of signed-up users

    function MySQLDB() {
        $this->connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $this->connection) or die(mysql_error());

        $this->num_members = -1;

        if (TRACK_VISITORS) {
            $this->calcNumActiveUsers();
            $this->calcNumActiveGuests();
        }
    }
};
?>
```

Comment: You put in the right host / user / password combination?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please ask your question within the body and format your code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

And make sure you type in the RIGHT username, password and database name... :)